# How to make somewhat similar radio sound effect from Battlestart Galactica?

Tags: sound, voice, radio

I have videos with timing that presents the effect. I may assume that there is some kind of chorus or flanger effect existing there but maybe I'm wrong...
And possibly there is multiple voices slightly detuned to create like effect of multiple voices simultaneously?

(video with timing, effect better heard in this one)

(first voice)

WARNING: videos have spoilers about show Battlestar Galactica, please listen only first appearance of this specific radio voice if you did not see the show (it's exceptional)

Answer (score 2):

That's a combination of effects.

Firstly, the obvious ones: use an EQ or a bandpass filter to remove the low frequencies and a little off the high end and add a touch of distortion. There are some filters with presets that include "Telephone", that's a good place to start.

Now the ones I think you're looking for: There seems to be some fast tremolo (LFO on the volume) running as well as some ring modulation that gives it that slightly metallic, phasing quality.

I would try for a chain that goes something like: light distortion -> EQ -> ring mod -> tremolo -> light distortion again. This mimics the signal path that you're trying to recreate: the headset mic set too close to the mouth, the preamp, the transmission, and the overloaded receiver amp running into a small speaker in the headset.

Be gentle with all of the effects because you could lose intelligibility on the voice if you run them too heavily.

Comment: Thank you! I will try everything you mentioned tomorrow!